# What is “aws_oracle_data.TCursorAttributes” in stored procedures while converting sql procedure in aws sct

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, oracle

While converting sql procedure in aws sct getting “aws_oracle_data.TCursorAttributes”. What is this for and how to modify this to execute this procedure in PostgreSQL?

Please explain what would be the replacement of that data type